# tensorflow-object-detection installation error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, installation

followed https://gilberttanner.com/blog/tensorflow-object-detection-with-tensorflow-2-creating-a-custom-model for the installation of https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

Basically, i completed the following steps without error

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
cd models/research
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
```

however when i tried
`python -m pip install .`

I got the following error

[ERROR LOG cmd install objection detection api](https://github.com/Zourunzhong/CNN-experiments/blob/master/error_log.txt)

(log uploaded to github as it is too long to be included within this post)

I updated pip and installed the latest version of visual studio c++ for this but to no avail

Comment: Your error log keeps repeating `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/` - have you tried this?

Comment: i install the Microsoft C++ Build Tools from this link https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ and during installation I selected: Workloads → Visual C++ build tools and for Install options: I selected “Windows 10 SDK". I also selected all python related workloads

Comment: I don't use Windows, but given that the error says specifically to use a different URL, I would suspect the Windows 10 SDK is not adequate, and that you need specifically C++ 14.0 from the URL supplied.

Comment: i installed both and it is still not working, the windows 10 sdk is an option within the installer in this link https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/. in fact the two installers are identical

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas at this point. As I said, I don't use Windows; the next step is probably to figure out why these packages don't believe you have C++ 14.0 installed (if it is installed, are they looking in the wrong place?).

Comment: Does this reference help to install [Object Detection API](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in your system?